# Error Getting and Reading URL with urllib/BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python

I'm currently learning how to use BeautifulSoup and practicing on a website to extract URLs from it. I'm getting this error when I try running:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yxty/Realex.py", line 7, in <module>
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Not Allowed
```

Here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.realtor.ca/Residential/map.aspx#CultureId=1&ApplicationId=1&RecordsPerPage=9&MaximumResults=9&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&StoreyRange=0-0&BedRange=0-0&BathRange=0-0&NumberofDays=4&LongitudeMin=-122.8479843139653&LongitudeMax=-122.68181610107467&LatitudeMin=49.244425437286374&LatitudeMax=49.303560989620294&SortOrder=A&SortBy=1&viewState=l&Longitude=-122.76490020752&Latitude=49.2740020751953&CurrentPage=1&ZoomLevel=13&PropertyTypeGroupID=1'

#opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_content = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing
content_soup = soup(page_content, "html.parser")
```

Comment: It is not your problem , it's server problem , see [405 status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405).

Comment: So have they implemented this on purpose to prevent the scraping of there website? If so is there ways around this on websites that give this error?

Comment: If you can, I would try using python's `requests` module. It will abstract a lot of the work in downloading webpages and let you focus on using BeautifulSoup. More information can be found [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: Ah okay, thank you! So use requests rather than urllib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Andrew Z recommended, try using `requests`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_url = 'https://www.realtor.ca/Residential/map.aspx#CultureId=1&ApplicationId=1&RecordsPerPage=9&MaximumResults=9&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&StoreyRange=0-0&BedRange=0-0&BathRange=0-0&NumberofDays=4&LongitudeMin=-122.8479843139653&LongitudeMax=-122.68181610107467&LatitudeMin=49.244425437286374&LatitudeMax=49.303560989620294&SortOrder=A&SortBy=1&viewState=l&Longitude=-122.76490020752&Latitude=49.2740020751953&CurrentPage=1&ZoomLevel=13&PropertyTypeGroupID=1'

req = requests.get(my_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
```

You can now parse the `soup`.